# How do I load the code for Kendo UI for React from a CDN?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

On the telerik site, I found the page

```
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/cdn-service#accessing-the-cdn
```

which mentions the CDN url

```
http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js
```

However, that file doesn't have the definitions for the React components Grid and GridCell.

This even though these definitions are in the NPM package @progress/kendo-react-grid.

Is there some other CDN url that gives me the .js file for Kendo UI for React?

Alternatively, if that file is not available from a CDN, is there a single file with all Kendo UI for React code that I can serve from my own server?

I have to load Kendo UI for React using a separate script tag. I can't use webpack or browserify to pack node modules.

Answer (score 0):

The kendo.all.min.js is the jquery suite.

The kendo react grid is here:

https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-grid@1.3.0/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-grid.js

It is per-package, and there is no something like all.js at-least at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The best public CDN is jsDelivr: https://www.jsdelivr.com/

It can serve up files and bundles directly for any NPM package, Github repo, or Wordpress plugin. You can even combine several files together into a single download.

Here's the package for Kendo UI React Grid: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@progress/kendo-react-grid

Download the file you need there or add it to the "selected files" on the right to build your own custom script bundle.